# Caeser cipher quesion

Tags: python

I have created the code, and I have made it to the output.  I have 2/3 runs correct for the check input, but I am missing part of the output when I enter
'Hello world!'

Everything runs and works.

```
    plainText = input("Enter a message: ")
    distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
    code = ""
    for ch in plainText:
        ordvalue = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
        if cipherValue > ord ('z'):
            cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordvalue + 1)
        code = code + chr(cipherValue)
    print(code)
```

The ciphered output is supposed to be `Lipps${svph%` , but I am getting `Lipps$asvph%` .  Just trying to find what I'm missing here.

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you want to understand why the output is `Lipps$asvph%`, or do you want to know how to change your code such that the output becomes `Lipps${svph%`?  If the latter is true, then please provide more details about how the function is expected to behave.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann The expected output is supposed to be 'Lipps${svph%' and I need to know what part of the code I'm missing that I'm only getting 'Lipps$asvph%'. I am supposed to be able to enter the input and get back the correct output.  I tried to explain as best I could.

Answer (score 0):

The caesar cipher only changes characters from the range `a..z`. All other characters are left unchanged. This restriction is missing from your code.

```
if 'a' <= ch <= 'z':
    cipherValue = ...
else:
    cipherValue = ch
```

By the way, in the `> ord('z')` case, you can make the code a lot simpler:

```
cipherValue -= 26
```

Or, if you don't want to write the number 26, but instead explain it:

```
cipherValue -= 1 + ord('z') - ord('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You expect that `'w'` (from `'Hello world!'`) should be transformed into `'{'` - instead of `'a'`.  But, this will not be the case.

From your example it can be deduced that `distance` was `4`:  `'H'` becomes `'L'`.  Then, the `'w'` will necessarily become `'a'` according to your algorithm: `ord('w') + 4` equals `ord('z') + 1`, because `ord('w') == ord('z') - 3`.  Consequently the then-clause of the `if` statement will be executed.  If you compute the result by replacing `ordvalue`  by `ord('z') - 3` you will see that the result will be `ord('a')`.

Since, as you have explained in the comment, you want to make your code turn the string `'Hello World!'` into `'Lipps${svph%'` you probably simply need to eliminate that part of the code that does the "overwrap" handling, that is, eliminate the code that handles the case that `cipherValue > ord ('z')`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what it is you're wanting me to edit.  This is an intro class, and it is not my strong suit, so I apologize ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

For those who were wondering - it was a language issue.  Instead of 'a' and 'z' it needed to be '~'.

Hopefully this is helpful for someone in the future.